# Why is OpenSubKey() returning null on my Windows 10 64-bit system?

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, registry

I'm developing x86 app to translate self-created "programming language" to assembler. At some point I need to get path to MASM32. I have read a couple of related topics, but they didn't help me, maybe because I'm new to C#.
MASM32 is situated here:`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MASM32`.
When I run my program, I always get "Masm32 is not found" message.
What should I do? Thanks in advance!

```
WindowsIdentity ident = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(ident);
        if (!myPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
        {
            string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
            RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
            rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user,
                        RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.CreateSubKey | RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ChangePermissions | RegistryRights.SetValue,
                        InheritanceFlags.None,
                        PropagationFlags.None,
                        AccessControlType.Deny));
        }
        try
        {
            RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
            RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
            RegistryView.Registry64);
            RegistryKey key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\"); 
            PathMasm32 = baseKey.GetValue("MASM32").ToString();
        }
        catch {
            erTxt = "Masm32 is not found";
              }
```

Comment: `"Masm32 is not found"` is *your* error message.  it will return that when anything goes wrong.

Comment: Don't use `catch` without an exception, otherwise you are throwing away all your problem details.

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: If this is an x86 app, then you should use the 32-bit view of the Registry and not search under Wow6432Node.

Comment: the actual exception is `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: I'll randomly guess that you are confusing a *value* with a *key*.  Try baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MASM32") to get somewhere.

Comment: Did you try the edited answer?

Comment: It finally works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not `OpenSubKey()` that is causing the null reference exception, but the `baseKey.GetValue().ToString()` call. The `baseKey.GetValue()` returns null (because in that case you are trying to get a value right under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE root node) and you invoke `ToString()` on a null reference. Instead of `baseKey.GetValue()`, you should try `key.GetValue()`, assuming MASM32 is really a value under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` which is highly unlikely.

```
key.GetValue("MASM32").ToString();
```

Security Note: If you are looking for the installation path of MASM32, even though I do not have any expertise on that, they clearly state that [The MASM32 SDK is registry safe and writes nothing to the registry.](http://www.masm32.com/installation.htm)

Thus, MASM32 is probably a KEY not a VALUE, therefore please execute this method and print the output of it, and you will see the key/value pairs registered under the MASM32 key assuming it exists at the registry path `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MASM32`

```
public static string GetMASM32LocationFromRegistry()
{
    RegistryKey localMachineRegistryKey;
    RegistryKey masm32RegistryKey;
    RegistryView currentRegistryView = RegistryView.Registry64;

    localMachineRegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, currentRegistryView);
    masm32RegistryKey = localMachineRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MASM32");

    if (masm32RegistryKey == null)
    {
        return @"ERROR: The registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MASM32 could not be found";
    }

    StringBuilder masm32RegistryKeyValuesBuilder = new StringBuilder("Key/Value pairs for registry key HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\MASM32:\r\n");
    foreach (string masm32RegistryKeyValueName in masm32RegistryKey.GetValueNames())
    {
        masm32RegistryKeyValuesBuilder.AppendFormat
        (
            "Key: [{0}], Value: [{1}], Value Type: [{2}]\r\n",
            masm32RegistryKeyValueName,
            masm32RegistryKey.GetValue(masm32RegistryKeyValueName),
            masm32RegistryKey.GetValueKind(masm32RegistryKeyValueName)
        );
    }

    return masm32RegistryKeyValuesBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: But the code is incorrect also try removing the trailing slash from open sub key too

Comment: Can you please tell me, what is incorrect, and how can I make it correct?

Comment: baseKey is HKLM, you try to get MASM32 from baseKey this means you are trying to get the value of HKLM\MASM32. I thought this could be the error, you should try to get the value from the key variable instead of baseKey variable. You say that you could not open the sub key, sorry, should check that when I have access to my PC tonight

Comment: What I mean is you open the sub key into the variable key but don't use this variable, probably by mistake, you use the subKey variable to call GetValue("MASM32")

Comment: I've updated my answer with many details and a code sample to enumarete and list the values under the MASM32 if it's a key. Please give it a try.